# Java delimeter new line

Tags: java

I have the following data:

```
Archeage/2009/mmorpg
CS:GO/2014/fps
Runescape/2007/mmorpg
```

I'm trying to read this with a simple `Scanner` and put data in to a `LinkedList` which has the following fields:

```
String pavadinimas;   //game name
int isleidimoMetai;  //game release year
String zanras;      //game genre
```

I am using the following delimeter:

```
public static final String delim = ("/|\\n");
```

Seems that when I read the `String zanras;      //game genre` it also reads a new line character and instead of getting `mmorpg` I get

```
mmorpg
(new line)
```

Main class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static LinkedList <Zaidimai> zaid = new LinkedList <Zaidimai>();
    String paketas = "src/lt/kvk/i7/engelaitis_justinas/";
    String duomenys = "failas.txt";
    String rezultatas = "rezultatas.txt";
    File file = new File(paketas + duomenys);
    File fileRez = new File(paketas + rezultatas);
    private Scanner scanner;
    private int size = 0;
    public static final String delim = ("/|\\r|\\n");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main main = new Main();

        Zaidimai prev = new Zaidimai();
        Zaidimai temp = prev;

        prev = main.sarasoSudarymas();

        main.meniu(prev, temp);
    }

    private void meniu(Zaidimai zaid, Zaidimai temp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("MENIU:");
        System.out.println("1. Saraso pildymas pagal reiksme");
        System.out.println("2. Saraso elemento paieska");
        System.out.println("3. Saraso elemento salinimas priekyje");
        System.out.println("4. Saraso spausdinimas");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Pasirinkite meniu numeri: ");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nr = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (nr) {
        case 1:
            sarasoPildymas(zaid, temp);
            break;
        case 2:
            sarasoPaieska(zaid, temp);
            break;
        case 3:
            salinimasPriekyje(zaid, temp);
            break;
        case 4:
            sarasoSpausdinimas(zaid, temp);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Tokio meniu pasirinkimo nera!");
            meniu(zaid, temp);
        }
    }

    private Zaidimai sarasoSudarymas() throws FileNotFoundException {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter(delim);
        Zaidimai prev = new Zaidimai();
        prev.pavadinimas = scanner.next();
        prev.isleidimoMetai = scanner.nextInt();
        prev.zanras = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(prev.zanras);
        prev.prev = null;
        size = 1;
        Zaidimai temp = prev;

        // dvipusio sudarymas
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            temp.next = new Zaidimai();
            temp.next.pavadinimas = scanner.next();
            temp.next.isleidimoMetai = scanner.nextInt();
            temp.next.zanras = scanner.next();
            temp.next.prev = temp;
            temp.next.next = prev;
            prev.prev = temp.next;
            temp = temp.next;
            size++;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    private void sarasoPildymas(Zaidimai zaid, Zaidimai temp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Iveskite reikiamus laukus: ");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Zaidimai naujas = new Zaidimai();
        System.out.print("pavadinimas: ");
        naujas.pavadinimas = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("isleidimoMetai: ");
        naujas.isleidimoMetai = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("zanras: ");
        naujas.zanras = scanner.next();

        System.out
                .println("naujas Zaidimai: " + naujas.pavadinimas + " " + naujas.isleidimoMetai + " " + naujas.zanras);
        pildytiDuomenis(temp, naujas, true);

        temp = zaid;

        meniu(zaid, temp);
    }

    private void pildytiDuomenis(Zaidimai temp, Zaidimai naujas, boolean rewrite) {
        PrintWriter writer;
        if (rewrite) {
            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                writer.println(naujas.pavadinimas + " " + naujas.isleidimoMetai + " " + naujas.zanras);
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sarasoPaieska(Zaidimai pr, Zaidimai temp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Paieska ---- Iveskite zanro pavadinima: ");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String zPav = scanner.next();
        boolean rasta = false;
        temp = pr;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (zPav == temp.pavadinimas) {
                System.out.println("Zaidimas rastas: " + temp.pavadinimas + " " + temp.isleidimoMetai + " " + temp.zanras);
                rezultatuSpausdinimas(pr, temp, true);
                rasta = true;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        if (!rasta)
            System.out.println("Zaidimas nerastas!");

        meniu(pr, temp);
    }

    private void rezultatuSpausdinimas(Zaidimai pr, Zaidimai temp, boolean rewrite){
        PrintWriter writer;
        if (rewrite) {
            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileRez, true));
                writer.println("Gauti saraso duomenys po asmenu paieskos: ");
                writer.println("*******************************************************************");
                writer.println(temp.pavadinimas + " " + temp.isleidimoMetai + " " + temp.zanras);
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sarasoSpausdinimas(Zaidimai zaid, Zaidimai temp) throws IOException {

        temp = zaid;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(temp.pavadinimas + " " + temp.isleidimoMetai + " " + temp.zanras);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        meniu(zaid, temp);
    }

    public void salinimasPriekyje(Zaidimai zaid, Zaidimai temp) throws IOException {
        temp = zaid;
        Zaidimai istrintas = new Zaidimai();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i == size - 2) {
                istrintas = temp.next;
                temp.next = zaid;
                temp.prev.next = temp;
                temp.next.prev = temp;
                size--;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        naikintiDuomenis(istrintas);
        meniu(zaid, temp);
    }

    private void naikintiDuomenis(Zaidimai temp) throws IOException {
        String[] lines = new String[200];
        String deleteLine = temp.pavadinimas + " " + temp.isleidimoMetai + " " + temp.zanras;
        int i = 0;
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            lines[i] = scanner.next() + " " + scanner.next() + " " + scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (lines[j].compareTo(deleteLine) != 0)
                writer.println(lines[j]);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Class Zaidimai:

```
public class Zaidimai {
    String pavadinimas;
    int isleidimoMetai;
    String zanras;
    Zaidimai next;
    Zaidimai prev;

}
```

How do I get rid of the new line?

Comment: write your code here please...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the format of your text file?

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this on Windows? Windows uses `\r\n` as a line separator. I'd suggest using `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @Mahdad , added full code.

Comment: Your current code seems to be using `/|\r|\n` delimiter which will cause other problem: in case of `\r\n` separator `next()` will return empty string between `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: @resueman Thanks, I was able to solve the problem with your suggestion! Now how do I appropriately close the question?

Comment: @Justin To close it, you need to click the check mark next to one of the answers down below , which will mark that answer as accepted. I'd suggest [Pshemo's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34910871/2499035), since it's covering the approach that it sounds like worked for you. If you don't feel that any of the answers adequately covered the problem though, you're welcome to post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your data separates lines using `\r\n` so your delimiter doesn't consume `\r` part.

Change delimiter to `"/|(\r?\n|\r)"` or since Java 8 you can use `\R` like `"/|\\R"`.

Answer (score 1):

An easier strategy would be to use the default Scanner delimiter, and use `scanner.nextLine()` followed by `String.split("/");`